# Regex replacement of hyphens?

Tags: regex

I am using a language where the syntax is `regex_replace(string, pattern, replacement_string)`.

I have a few strings which look like this `s=123-21785-15643411`.

I am looking for a pattern to replace `s` with `1232178515643411`.

What would be the pattern such that I can do `regex_replace(s, pattern, '')` and remove the hyphens from my string?

Comment: Feel free to tag the language as well.

Comment: @anubhava what would be the pattern to do so?

Comment: Replace `-` with `''`

Comment: There is only one flavor where `-` must be escaped - Lua. But those are not regular expressions, Lua uses so called Lua patterns.

Comment: Doesn't need a regex, use a string replace method if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Example could be like:

```js
s="123-21785-15643411";

s = s.replace(/-/g,"");

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
import re
s = "123-21785-15643411"
regex = r"-"
res = re.sub(regex, '', s)
print(res)
```

Returns:

```
1232178515643411
```

but string methods are much more direct:

```
print(s.replace('-', ''))
```

Giving the same result